# Facebook Graph Event query no address

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just read this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event

and it seems as if there is no data about the location of an event. Only a "Page" Attribute which in turn has a contact_address value. Now my question is: What about those events that don't belong to a place? They have addresses too in FB but there seems to be no way to get this data from the FB graph API. Or did I miss something? Does anybody know a workaround to get hold of this data?

We wanna analyze a bunch of events and put them all on a map. but that won't work if we cannot get the address for the event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since V2.3 of the Graph API, the location/place information is more consistent. You can read more about that here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes:

> **Consistent Place Data** - Content objects tagged with a place now share a consistent place data structure which contains the ID, name
>   the location of the place. This includes Events, Photos, Videos,
>   Statuses and Albums. As a result, the venue and location fields have
>   been removed from the Event node. Developers should access the place
>   field instead.

This means indeed that only Event that use a Page as a location have a location. You should follow the 'Place' field, which gives you an Page.

If you have access to version V2.2 of the API, you can still use the 'location' field instead. That will return you the address as defined on the Event.